# list indiced must be integers or slices not tuples

Tags: python

What I want to do is to import only 6 rows into 2D list here is part my code :

```
cur = connection.cursor()
sql_select_query = """select * from image"""
cur.execute(sql_select_query)
record = cur.fetchall()

imgs_recently = [["","",""],["","",""],["","",""],["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]
  
for row in record:
    imgs_recently[row][0] = row[0] # img id
    imgs_recently[row][1] = row[2] # location
    imgs_recently[row][2] = row[5] # img path
```

I'm guising that my mistake is that i used row as array and as index ? If so how can i resolve this error ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Simply hard-code the value of `row`; look at what you're using for a subscript for `imgs_recently`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `row` as list indices that's why its throwing this kind of error.
so in you case `row` is a tuple, you have to use integers or slices. so you can try with `row[n]`

Answer (score 1):

```
imgs_recently = [ [ row[0], row[2], row[5] ] for row in record[:6] ]
```

That's it.